# Ubuntu 14.04 DVD playback stuttering

Tags: 14.04, vlc, dvd, playback

Running into a problem playing DVD's on 14.04 LTS. I have installed all libs in various sections and do get the menus and initial menu videos to play however when the main movie plays the video become garbled. I also have a Windows XP VM running under VMWare player and it plays smooth with VLC so I don't think this is a hardware problem. Also have installed the lib-bluray stuff and keys...

VLC is caughing up many errors while the video plays. Seems to be bad dvd decrypt keys somehow??

Ubuntu 14.04 LTS x64
VLC 2.2.0-git Weatherwax

dmesg for bluray player

scsi 3:0:0:0: CD-ROM            MATSHITA BD-MLT UJ265     1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
sr0: scsi3-mmc drive: 62x/62x writer dvd-ram cd/rw xa/form2 cdda caddy
cdrom: Uniform CD-ROM driver Revision: 3.20
sr 3:0:0:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr0

vlc errors during main movie playback:

[mpeg2video @ 0x7fb2ec055820] slice mismatch
[mpeg2video @ 0x7fb2ec055820] mb incr damaged
[mpeg2video @ 0x7fb2ec055820] invalid mb type in B Frame at 37 11
[mpeg2video @ 0x7fb2ec055820] mb incr damaged
[mpeg2video @ 0x7fb2ec055820] ac-tex damaged at 21 12
[mpeg2video @ 0x7fb2ec055820] ac-tex damaged at 3 13
[mpeg2video @ 0x7fb2ec055820] ac-tex damaged at 3 14
[mpeg2video @ 0x7fb2ec055820] invalid mb type in B Frame at 20 15
[mpeg2video @ 0x7fb2ec055820] invalid mb type in B Frame at 14 16
[mpeg2video @ 0x7fb2ec055820] ac-tex damaged at 28 18
[mpeg2video @ 0x7fb2ec055820] invalid mb type in B Frame at 17 18
[mpeg2video @ 0x7fb2ec055820] mb incr damaged
[mpeg2video @ 0x7fb2ec055820] ac-tex damaged at 8 20
[mpeg2video @ 0x7fb2ec055820] invalid mb type in B Frame at 7 21
[mpeg2video @ 0x7fb2ec055820] ac-tex damaged at 17 22
[mpeg2video @ 0x7fb2ec055820] ac-tex damaged at 1 23
[mpeg2video @ 0x7fb2ec055820] mb incr damaged
[mpeg2video @ 0x7fb2ec055820] ac-tex damaged at 14 25
[mpeg2video @ 0x7fb2ec055820] ac-tex damaged at 4 26
[mpeg2video @ 0x7fb2ec055820] mb incr damaged
[mpeg2video @ 0x7fb2ec055820] mb incr damaged
[mpeg2video @ 0x7fb2ec055820] mb incr damaged
[mpeg2video @ 0x7fb2ec055820] invalid cbp at 23 0
[mpeg2video @ 0x7fb2ec055820] slice mismatch
[mpeg2video @ 0x7fb2ec055820] slice mismatch
[mpeg2video @ 0x7fb2ec055820] ac-tex damaged at 19 3
[mpeg2video @ 0x7fb2ec055820] mb incr damaged
[mpeg2video @ 0x7fb2ec055820] slice mismatch
[mpeg2video @ 0x7fb2ec055820] mb incr damaged
[mpeg2video @ 0x7fb2ec055820] invalid mb type in B Frame at 5 7
[mpeg2video @ 0x7fb2ec055820] ac-tex damaged at 10 8
[mpeg2video @ 0x7fb2ec055820] invalid mb type in B Frame at 1 9
[mpeg2video @ 0x7fb2ec055820] mb incr damaged
[mpeg2video @ 0x7fb2ec055820] invalid cbp at 15 11
[mpeg2video @ 0x7fb2ec055820] ac-tex damaged at 27 12
[mpeg2video @ 0x7fb2ec055820] ac-tex damaged at 2 14
[mpeg2video @ 0x7fb2ec055820] mb incr damaged
[mpeg2video @ 0x7fb2ec055820] invalid mb type in B Frame at 13 16
[mpeg2video @ 0x7fb2ec055820] mb incr damaged
[mpeg2video @ 0x7fb2ec055820] invalid mb type in B Frame at 7 18

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Do videos already in your HDD play fine? In other words, does this issue occur only when you play videos from your DVD? Please add this info to your question description..(You can do this by pressing the 'edit' button above...

Comment: Can you add your solution as an answer please, instead of an edit to the question? It's [totally OK](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/).

Answer (score 2):

"Turns out the  `~./dvdcss` keys for this DVD were corrupt. I deleted the keys for the DVD and all is well."

Comment: Taken from the answer. If TS ever comes back to create an answer feel free to vote to delete this :)